# Why are ffmpeg loudnorm and ebur128 measurements different

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

When I run an audio file through FFMpeg's 'loudnorm' filter, I get the following:

```
> ffmpeg -i <file> -af loudnorm=print_format=json -f null -
...
"input_i" : "-13.87",
"input_tp" : "0.06",
"input_lra" : "8.50",
"input_thresh" : "-24.45",
...
```

When I run the same audio file through the ebur128 filter, I get the
following:

```
> ffmpeg -i <file>  -af ebur128 -f null -
Integrated loudness:
   I:         -13.8 LUFS
   Threshold: -24.4 LUFS
Loudness range:
   LRA:         8.7 LU
   Threshold: -34.3 LUFS
   LRA low:   -20.1 LUFS
   LRA high:  -11.4 LUFS
```

Why are these measurements different? Even if rounding would be towards 0,
that would not explain the LRA difference? Are these filters measuring different things?

Comment: That could have many different causes, different sampling algorithm, different sample rates, different rounding of different data types, computers having problems with rounding anyways, etc. If you want to know it in detail, have a look at the sourcecode of [loudnorm](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavfilter/af_loudnorm.c) and [ebur128](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavfilter/ebur128.c)

Comment: Also you are comparing one value to another with 10x the precision. In any case it is just a **very minor** deviation, I doubt anyone could hear a 0,05dB difference in loudness